# Parametrise the circle centered at $ \ (1,1,-1) \ $ with radius equal to $ 3 $

Tags: parametrization

Parametrise the circle centered at $ \ (1,1,-1) \ $ with radius equal to $ 3  $ in the plane $ x+y+z=1 $ with positive orientation . $$ $$ I have thought the parametriation:

\begin{align} x(t)=1+ 3 \cos (t) \hat j +3 \sin (t)  \hat k \\ y(t)=1+3 \cos (t) \hat i+3 \sin (t) \hat k \\ z(t)=-1+3 \cos (t) \hat i +3 \sin (t) \hat j  , \ \ 0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi \end{align}  But I am not sure . **Any help is there ?**

Comment: Do you have $\;x(t)+y(t)+z(t)=1\;$ ...?

Comment: yes. it is in the plane x+y+z=1 @DonAntonio

Comment: yes . I think the normal vector (1,1,1) to the plane x+y+z=1 might work.

Comment: @SakethMalyala No, I don't think it is. Look at the $\;k\,-$ coordinate...

Comment: but it says that in the question @DonAntonio

Comment: @SakethMalyala I don't get your point... The $\;k\,-$ coordinate of the OP's parametrization shows the proposed circle isn't on the given plane, unless I miss something here...

Comment: yes $ \hat i=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} $

Comment: my bad. i thought you were referring to what x, y, z *should* be. i was just reading the question. you meant of his proposed parametrization @DonAntonio

Comment: @SakethMalyala Yes, of course! I want the OP to realize his proposed parametrization isn't on the given plane and thus cannot be correct.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbf u = (\frac {\sqrt 2}{2} \mathbf i - \frac {\sqrt 2}{2} \mathbf j)\\
\mathbf v = (\frac {\sqrt 6}{6} \mathbf i + \frac {\sqrt 6}{6} \mathbf j -\frac {\sqrt 6}{3} \mathbf k)$

$(x,y,z) = (1,1,-1) + 3\mathbf u \cos t + 3\mathbf v \sin t\\ 
x = 1 + 3\frac {\sqrt 2}{2} \cos t + \frac{\sqrt {6}}{2} \sin t\\
y = 1 - 3\frac {\sqrt 2}{2} \cos t + \frac {\sqrt {6}}{2} \sin t\\
z = -1  - \sqrt {6} \sin t$

Comment: how did you get $ u \ \ and \ \ v $ ?

Comment: I did not understand how you got $ u \ \ and \ \  v $

Comment: I was looking for vectors that lie in the plane (are perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$), have unit length and are perpendicular to each other.  $(1,-1,0), (1,1,-2),$ lie in the plane and are perpendicular to each other.  Then I unitized them.

Answer (score 1):

The plane can be parameterised as follows
\begin{eqnarray*}
x=1+t \\
y=1+s \\
z=-1-t-s.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now substitute this into the equation for the sphere $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z+1)^2=9$. We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
t^2+s^2+(t+s)^2=9 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Rearrange this to

\begin{eqnarray*}
(2t+s)^2+3s^2=18
\end{eqnarray*}
This can be paramterised

\begin{eqnarray*}
s=\sqrt{6} \sin(\theta) \\
2t+s= \sqrt{18} \cos(\theta)
\end{eqnarray*}
Now substitute back into the parameterisation of the plane

\begin{eqnarray*}
x=1+ \frac{\sqrt{18} \cos(\theta) - \sqrt{6} \sin(\theta)}{2} \\
y=1+\sqrt{6} \sin(\theta) \\
z=-1-\frac{\sqrt{18} \cos(\theta)+\sqrt{6} \sin(\theta)}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

The intersection of the sphere 
$$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z+1)^2=9$$
and the plane
$$x+y+z=1$$
can be parametrised by spherical coordinates :
$$x=1+3\sin (\phi)\cos (\theta) $$
$$y=1+3\sin (\phi)\sin (\theta) $$
$$z=-1-3\sin (\phi)(\cos (\theta)+\sin (\theta)) $$.

with $0\le \theta \le 2\pi $ and $0\le \phi \le \pi$.

Comment: $x,y,z$ as parameterized above does not lie on the surface of the sphere.